# Is there a way add constraint like x(y+z)<0 in LpSolve?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, lpsolve

I want to add constraints like

```
0.2(x1+x2+y1+y2+900)>=1;
```

in LpSolve but i've got Parse error. i've tried to like but still got error:

```
0.2*(x1+x2+y1+y2+900)>=1;
```

How should I specify for .lp format?
Thank you.

Comment: i did it like 0.2 x1 + 0.2 x2 + 0.2 y1 +0.2y2 and it works.

Comment: don't forget you can answer your own question (and accept your answer) if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
0.2*x1 + 0.2*x2 + 0.2*y1 + 0.2*y2 + 180 >=1;
```

And it should work. (That is, perform the distributive multiplication manually.) A modeling language like JuMP or CVXPY would handle this automatically.